# Everywhere a new activity is referenced

Tags: android, android-studio

I've created a new activity in Android Studio - call it New_Name_2. Half way through I realize that name is poor naming convention and want to refactor it to Second_Activity.

Using refactor -> Rename I renamed content_New_Name_2.xml, activity_New_Name_2.xml, and New_Name_2.java

The name has changed in the Android Manifest.

However when I set the onclick listener I receive a fatal crash:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.xx.Second_Activity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
```

I'm assuming I missed a place to refactor the name. When I create a basic activity with Android Studio where is it referenced besides:

- Content xml
- Activity xml
- Java class
- Android Manifest

__ Edit __ included onClickListener

```
    btnSecond = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnSecond);
    btnSecond.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Second_Activity.class));
        }
    });
```

SOLVED:  the Second_Activity class had an error in an onClickListener. I had something like btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id. WRONG ID WAS HERE)

Thanks all!

Comment: Pretty sure your activity is fine, but not your onClickListener on a null object.

Comment: stay cursor on name and press Shift+F6 and if you change it will be changed everywhere where used

Comment: Pasted in the onClickListener. Not seeing how it could be null unless the I screwed up refactoring the class

Comment: How does your second activity class look like?

Comment: @Muratk. I just commented out everything except the default onCreate() etc. If I comment out all of that it works.. hm problem must be in that class itself and not the main activity where I thought it was

Comment: Got it - the Second_Activity class had an error in an onClickListener. I had something like btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id. WRONG ID WAS HERE)

Answer (score 1):

When read `ComponentInfo` try to do a clean.

Go to `Build` > `Clean Project` and then try to run your app.

**EDIT (good practice)**

It's a good practice, after `findViewById()`, try to check if the view (`btnSecond` in your case) is not null.

```
btnSecond = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnSecond);
if (btnSecond != null)
    btnSecond.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```

Comment: Cleaning didn't work unfortunately. Setting a != null test still gives me a crash. Setting to == null out of curiosity, no crash, but no function.